# What is the different in Django 3 ASGI and Django 2 + Channels?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, asgi

`django-channels` is on my 1st list of material I am going to learn during this new year. But Django 3 also has ASGI feature without any document on it. Then I doubt that what is the different between `django-channels` use cases VS Django 3 ASGI?

Comment: For the moment Django 3 only adds the functionality, that your Django application can run as ASGI application. But no extra real benefits beyond that. It allows you to switch over to uvicorn already. You still need django-channels for its features.

Comment: I think so. Thank you very much